# How do I download KB updates for Office XP under Windows 10 that are no longer on Microsoft website?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, office-xp

Windows Update is reporting that I require 7 updates for Office 2002 / Visio 2002, but Windows updates fail with `Error 0x80096004`

How do I locate and download these updates manually? The original KB articles and/or their download links don't appear to be available.

The KB numbers are:

**Office**

- KB833858
- KB837253
- KB904018
- KB905758
- KB911701
- KB913471

**Visio**

- KB830242

So, the files I'm looking for are:

- officexp-kb833858-fullfile-enu.exe
- officexp-kb837253-fullfile-enu.exe
- officexp-KB904018-FullFile-ENU.exe
- officexp-KB905758-FullFile-ENU.exe
- officexp-KB911701-FullFile-ENU.exe
- officexp-KB913471-FullFile-ENU.exe
- Visio2002-KB830242-FullFile-ENU.EXE

Comment: As an alternative, you might want to try libreoffice, its completely free and it reads and writes standard office documents all the way up to 2016.  http://www.libreoffice.org

Comment: Thanks @cybernard, Already have LibreOffice, but I need the VBA and third-party COM-addin capabilities

Answer (score 7):

While I was able to find a few of these files hosted on CNET and Russian FTP servers, I don't trust any download from a site that includes `cnet.com` or `.ru`

However, thanks to the Internet Archive's Wayback machine, I was able to locate archived download links for all 7 files.

- [officexp-kb833858-fullfile-enu.exe](http://web.archive.org/web/20051202060433/http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/5/7/25750dd8-e66e-4099-95b4-216c0542d2f1/officexp-kb833858-fullfile-enu.exe)
- [officexp-kb837253-fullfile-enu.exe](http://web.archive.org/web/20060216130041/http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/4/E/54ED43C3-DFE0-408D-BEEB-99672B7033D8/officexp-kb837253-fullfile-enu.exe)
- [officexp-KB904018-FullFile-ENU.exe](http://web.archive.org/web/20140228142830/http://download.microsoft.com/download/b/5/4/b543a4ea-ec0d-4032-934a-de120d76f012/officexp-KB904018-FullFile-ENU.exe)
- [officexp-KB905758-FullFile-ENU.exe](http://web.archive.org/web/20060513183457/http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/c/2/ec238e91-c560-4bf3-bc57-7eb0cfc90236/officexp-KB905758-FullFile-ENU.exe)
- [officexp-KB911701-FullFile-ENU.exe](http://web.archive.org/web/20070308200258/http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/3/d/43dbb8ee-10a2-44a7-baa6-eea7884e3375/officexp-KB911701-FullFile-ENU.exe)
- [officexp-KB913471-FullFile-ENU.exe](http://web.archive.org/web/20070320080102/http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/7/4/774327ab-be17-4cd7-8b3e-e98a9006ed53/officexp-KB913471-FullFile-ENU.exe)
- [Visio2002-KB830242-FullFile-ENU.EXE](http://web.archive.org/web/20130206060706/http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/4/3/743908a4-9e56-4f72-b8d6-501c54fcf089/Visio2002-KB830242-FullFile-ENU.EXE)
- [officexp-KB980371-FullFile-ENU.exe](https://web.archive.org/web/20131003084641/http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/6/0/7608579C-B6D1-493A-B8AE-F9D4AE708EB9/officexp-KB980371-FullFile-ENU.exe)

Comment: I did not know about the Internet Archive's Wayback machine. Very helpful!

Comment: Best to use >>>>>https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are best Best to use  the [official Microsoft site](http://Best%20to%20use%20%3E%3E%3E%3E%3Ecatalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx) to download KB's