# Downloading Windows updates for old software

Tags: windows-update, microsoft-office-2003

How can I download all updates to Office 2003 (in case Microsoft stops support via Windows Update)? When I try I get to "Page not found" and "This page cannot be displayed", and my Google-fu is insufficient to find/download most of the updates. I have found a few with names like `office2003-KB925256-FullFile-ENU.exe` but most elude me. I have tried on my Windows 10 system and on an ancient XP system. I found [How do I download KB updates for Office XP under Windows 10 that are no longer on Microsoft website?](https://superuser.com/questions/1185038/how-do-i-download-kb-updates-for-office-xp-under-windows-10-that-are-no-longer-o) suggesting use of the Wayback machine but not how it works.

Where/how can I download a complete set of updates? And if possible both in English (ENU) and Dutch (NLD).

Background: with every release Office seems to become safer (good) and more intelligent (not good in my opinion). I happen to have a legal copy of Office 2003 which I am still using, and it receives about 35 updates when I install it on a new PC, but how long will this support last? So, locked down as I am, I tried to download all the updates to burn to a CD. A long time ago I managed a similar trick with Windows 98, but I'm having no success with Office. I have Office SP3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I download KB updates for Office XP under Windows 10 that are no longer on Microsoft website?](https://superuser.com/questions/1185038/how-do-i-download-kb-updates-for-office-xp-under-windows-10-that-are-no-longer-o)

Comment: [All Office 2003 Updates](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=Office%202003).  Microsoft has yet to remove updates for Windows 2000 from the Windows Update Catalog.  *I think it's safe to say Microsoft does not make updates unavailable unless they are pulled for a reason or replaced by a newer update.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm self-answering so that anyone else can do this or a similar action. @Moab and @Ramhound pointed me to `https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx` where everything can be found *if you know how to search*. This is what I did:

1. I installed Office2003 and also SP3 (`Office2003SP3-KB923618-FullFile-ENU.exe`) and `FileFormatConverters.exe` which I already had.
2. Run Windows Update (several times) and note the KB numbers of all updates (see note A). Create an empty directory (folder) for each of them. Or use my list given below.
3. Go to `catalog.update.microsoft` and search on each KB number; download the appropriate one(s) for your configuration/language to the appropriate directory. In a few cases there may be more than one download and/or the download may be language-dependent.
4. The downloads will be cabinet (CAB) files with names like `fm20_86bc3fbc23d82c942ebe6e5b5542dd49572d26a5.cab`. Double-clicking the CAB file will show the patch inside it; double-clicking again will extract the patch as an MSP (Windows Installer Patch) file (in this case `FM20.msp`). Be sure to extract the patch to the right directory, some names are not unique. If you are doing multiple languages, append a suffix like `_EN` or `_NL` to the MSP file. You can then delete the CAB file.
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 for all KB numbers. Save your work (in my case 393MB in 43 directories) in a safe place.

After a new Office installation, you can visit each directory and double-click each MSP file to install the patch. You might like to do a clean install, install your patch set, and verify that Windows Update finds nothing.

Notes:
A. On Windows 10 you need to go to `Settings > Updates > Advanced Options` and enable `Receive updates for other Microsoft products` before clicking `Check For Updates`. You can then find the updates in `View Update History`. In a few cases you may need a few more clicks to get the KB number (eg "Microsoft Office File Validation Add-in" takes you to a web page address including 2501584 which is the KB number.)

B. It does not seem to matter what order you install the patches; I did them in numerical order.

C. In at least one case (KB943452) there is an update for Dutch (NLD) but not for English; other languages may also show variations.

Here is my list for office 2003 (32-bit, EN and NL) YMMV!

907417
943452
943973
947319
955439
974554
975051
978551
980373
980923
981716
2288613
2289163
2293428
2449798
2493523
2501584
2526297
2535812
2539581
2543854
2553065
2596904
2687626
2726929
2760494
2760574
2810048
2817474
2825621
2825645
2850047
2863822
2878299
2878303
2881030
2984938
3085549
3203484
3213641
3213644
4011715
4011717
4018354

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound  for your tip. Everyone: if this is usable (ie no negative comments in a week) I'll mark it as Accepted.

Comment: For anyone wanting to update Access 2003, after applying SP3, you need hotfix KB981716 aka MS10-044.  This supersedes hotfixes KB945674 and KB970623.

Comment: Feb 2023 doing a new install I discovered 2543854 is required; list edited (and I can confirm that my procedure still works)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, as soon as I followed Note A "On Windows 10 you need to go to Settings > Updates > Advanced Options and enable Receive updates for other Microsoft products " it automatically installed the updates.  I did not have to search the catalog one by one.  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) ensure your answer adds something really new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.